# Работа с контейнерами стандартной библиотеки C++ в Python

Tags: python, c++, linux, ctypes

Столкнулся с проблемой при работе с контейнером стандартной библиотеки C++.
В Python, ctypes имеет очень ограниченный набор типов ( вернее исключительно типы C).

В моем случае:
Есть скомпилированный файл libtopy.so
Заголовок topy.h:

```
#ifndef TOPY_TOPY_H
#define TOPY_TOPY_H
#include <vector>
#include <string>

extern "C" {
    bool saveImageByCPPCode(const std::vector<unsigned char> &vec, const std::string &filename);
}

#endif //TOPY_TOPY_H
```

Принты о начале записи и её конце - распечатывает. Но сохранение - Нет.
Код на python:

```
import ctypes
import pathlib
import os



libname = pathlib.Path().absolute() / "libtopy.so"
lib = ctypes.CDLL(libname)

b = "asdasd"
b = str.encode(b)
b = (ctypes.c_ubyte * 6)


lib.saveImageByCPPCode(vector = b, string ="/home/ilya/cmd_save/img.jpg")
```

Если запускать код на C++, все работает без проблем и сохраняет.
Прошу подсказать, **существует ли инструмент, работающий с контейнерами стандартной библиотеки С++?** ctypes увы, не подходит.
пробовал использовать просто строку - как байты, картинку конвертировал или принимал в пост запросе - не выполняется запись (скорее всего не может). Проблема возникает с отправкой Вектора.

Comment: Экспортируйте наружу функцию с сишными параметрами (что-то типа `unsigned char *`, `size_t` (для указания размера массива из первого параметра), `char *`), а внутри уже переводите в контейнеры C++.

Comment: Благодарю, попробую так.

Comment: Ну так оно и называется ctypes, а не с++types. Чтобы работать с типами С++ необходимо писать обертку.

Comment: Спасибо за разъяснение. Второй день этим занимаюсь. Будем на СИ обертку делать.

Comment: up.
ctypes предназначен для работы с СИ языком.
Для работы с C++ нужно делать обертку на СИ. Спасибо [insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365/insolor) и [user7860670](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/272035/user7860670) за объяснения.

Comment: использовать плюсовые типы внутри `extern "C"` - это так себе удовольствие.